# VSCode freezing linux in a project containing node_modules

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have a React project which contains around 165 MBs of `node_modules` folder.

Everytime I start VSCode and start working on this project, it freezes randomly(impossible to predict) rendering entire computer unresponsive(both mouse and keyboard). I have 4GB RAM in my system and I believe it is large enough to support VSCode.

Also, this problem doesn't happenes with other projects which do not contain large files as node_modules, like java project. So, with the help from other answers on this topic, things I have tried:

1. setting `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`
2. Excluded .js files and node_modules from fileExclude and fileWatcherExclude
3. Tried running code with `--disable-extensions` flag
4. Disabled Hardware accleleration in argv.json of vscode
5. Turned off `git.autorefresh`

But none of the above thing worked for me. I have ubuntu 18.04 and VSCode's version is 1.46.1.

Please guide me to the right way to solve my problem.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I have increased my laptop's RAM from 4 to 8 GB and now that problem has almost disappeared. Though, I was unable to find the root cause of this problem.

Comment: It still happens now, but that happens only for 2-3 second when cursor doesn't move with mouse or keyboard. After 2-3 seconds, it becomes quite normal again.